# IP Packet Processing

Tags: networking

```
Host A (eth0-1500 bytes)--->(eth0-1500) Router (eth1-1000)---> (eth0-1000) Host B
```

Can you please explain this case how Router process packet? if Host A send data size of 4000 bytes. Here Router receive the fragmented packet of size 1500 bytes, but out going interface of Router is 1000 bytes, then Router will fragment the packet again and send to Host B or Router will send ICMP Error Message to Host A.

Comment: You have explained it very well.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Host A can't send 4000 bytes of data without a transport protocol with an MTU of 1500 byte on the link.

Assuming TCP (20 byte packet overhead) over IPv4 (20 byte overhead), host A segments the data into two 1460 byte and one 1080 byte segments. Due to a lower MTU on the 2nd segment, the router needs to fragment these packets of 1500 and 1120 bytes into 1000, 500, 1000, 500, 1000, and 120 bytes. If Host A sets *Don't Fragment* the router returns a "Fragmentation required" and drops the packets.

Using IPv6 (40 byte packet overhead), the path MTU is discovered first and the resulting segment size of 940 bytes is used (resulting in 4x 1000 + 1x 300 byte packets).